# Can't retrive firestore location and timestamp objects to vuetify data tables

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, datatable, vuetify.js

Can not retrive firestore document **Geopoint**(location) and **Timestamp**(date and time) objects to vue.js vuetify dataTables. Locations show **[object Object]** instead of **location data**(longitude:'' and latitude:'') on table column.Timestamp does not retrive date and time.It just retrives **Timestamp(seconds=1631868600, nanoseconds=0)**.[Click to see table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWb4H.jpg)

db.js for firestore

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import Vue from 'vue'
import { firestorePlugin } from 'vuefire'

Vue.use(firestorePlugin)
// Get a Firestore instance
export const db = firebase
  .initializeApp({ projectId: 'f*********-9efac' })
  .firestore()

// Export types that exists in Firestore
// This is not always necessary, but it's used in other examples
const { Timestamp, GeoPoint } = firebase.firestore
export { Timestamp, GeoPoint }
```

DataTable.vue

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      Tag Information
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        label="Search Tag ID"
        single-line
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table 
      :headers="headers"
      :items="Tags"
      :search="search"
      item-key="tagId"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import { db } from '../firebase/db'
import { Timestamp, GeoPoint } from "../firebase/db";
export default {
  name: 'DataTable',
  props: {
    tagId: Number,
    loosed: Boolean,
    location: GeoPoint,
    timeStamp: Timestamp,

  },
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
      headers: [
        { text: 'Tag-ID', value: 'tagId' },
        { text: 'Loosed?', value: 'loosed' },
        { text: "location", value: 'location', width: "30%" },
        { text: 'TimeStamp', value: 'timeStamp' },
      ],
      Tags: [],
    }
  },
  firestore: {
    Tags: db.collection('Tags'),
  },
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the [GeoPoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint) you need to use the `latitude` and `longitude` properties for the Timestamp you need to use the [`toDate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) method.

There are actually two sections about that in the vuefire [documentation](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#using-the-data-bound-by-vuefire).

To display these values in the data table, for the GeoPoint you can directly use the `latitude` or `longitude` property in the `value` property of the corresponding objects of the `header` Array, as follows:

```
  headers: [
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { text: "latitude", value: 'location.latitude', width: "30%" },
    { text: "longitude", value: 'location.longitude', width: "30%" }
  ],
```

For the timestamp it is bit more complex, since toDate(§) is a function: you need to use one of the two approaches detailed in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7066), i.e. a computed value or `<template v-slot:...">`.

Comment: It was helpful and now the location data is okay.but toDate() function having errors.

Comment: "toDate() function having errors" => yes, as explained in the answer you need to adopt another approach: either a [computed value](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7066#issuecomment-659886481) or using [`<template v-slot:...">`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7066#issuecomment-659886481).